# How to share ppp0 to wlan0 with redsocks

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, iptables

I can't understand the meaning of this:

[image]

I have a USB modem along with a USB Wifi router, and I use redsocks for `ppp0`. Then I want to forward the incoming connection from Wifi to `redsocks`.
I have searched over Google on how to route forward the connection from `wlan0` to `ppp0`, but none is working for me.

my iptables rules so far:

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS

# Ignore LANs and some other reserved addresses.
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything else should be redirected to port 31338
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 31338

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

I'm looking for `iptables` rule for doing that. can you give me the rules?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my rules to share ppp0 connection with wlan0.

```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
    iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

Also in my case, I flush all rules before applying new one and it is working gracefully.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's not working for me